# Can't create a Excel document MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, excel, jquery-ui

Hi i'm trying to create an excel document using this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325103/MVC-Grid-to-Excel-file-download), but it does not return anything then it's called, it does not throw any exception in the code nor in the view.

This is the method in the controllere:

```
  public ActionResult ExportData(string toDateTime, string fromDateTime)
        {
            var gv = new GridView
            {
                DataSource = _fttDataProvider.SelectRangeWasteRegistrations(Convert.ToDateTime(toDateTime), Convert.ToDateTime(fromDateTime), 1).ToList()
            };
            gv.DataBind();

            return new DownloadFileActionResult(gv, "Cars.xls");
        }
```

This is the javascript that is calling it

```
$('#SubmitExport').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var toDate = $("#toDateTime").val();
            var fromDate = $("#fromDateTime").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ol.url("~/Home/ExportData"),
                data: { "toDateTime": toDate, "fromDateTime": fromDate },
            });
```

The reason i'm using javascript is to the get values from the two jquery ui datepickers i'm using to get the to and from dates.

```
 $("#fromDateTime").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#toDateTime").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $("#toDateTime").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#fromDateTime").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
```

Comment: 1) Do you have any javascript error when clicking SubmitExport button? 2) Did you try to set a breakpoint inside the ExportData action?

Comment: No i have have no errors in the JavaScript. 
Yes i have tried to set breakpoint in the Controller, and i can see that it contains 20+ rows in the GridView, and there are no other errors.

Comment: Then it looks like the problem is in DownloadFileActionResult. First you can try to check in Network tab of developer toolbar what is being returned in response to the mentioned request. What HTTP code, response body, etc.

Comment: Then looking at the post message. It contains something like this:<div>
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">WasteId</th><th scope="col">OrderNo</th><th scope="col">Amount</th><th scope="col">Description</th><th scope="col">WasteRegistrationType</th><th scope="col">CreateTime</th>
  </tr><tr>